# How do I use string.tr to replace double quotes with single ones in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How do I use string.tr to replace double quotes with single ones in Ruby?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
'abc "def" ghi'.tr('"', "'")  # => abc 'def' ghi
```

Comment: ahh, it is always the simple solutions that are hard to find.

Answer (score 4):

Besides `tr`, you can also use `gsub`

```
irb(main):001:0> 'abc "def" ghi'.gsub(/"/,"'")
=> "abc 'def' ghi"
```

Comment: `tr` is preferable since `gsub` is much slower: https://github.com/JuanitoFatas/fast-ruby#stringgsub-vs-stringtr-code